# React Boostrap Card Component Image loading after a long time or never show-up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, bootstrap-4, loading

I'm really new to react & react-boostrap.
I'm making a yelp-like web app that will use the YELP rest api to look-up restaurant and sort them. Currently it's still a static page and loading the same restaurant object multiple times inside a list of CARDS items.

I have been seeing that sometimes it takes much longer to load the pictures and sometimes it don't load the pictures at all unless I click manually reload.

Why is this happening, what can I do about it?

Tried exploring the react web debugger, but since I'm quite new, no much success?is there a way to check loading time of scripts or something?

Code Src: https://github.com/Weltgeist/ravenous

Current commit: c00dc0b

Business.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Business.css';
import business from './BusinessData' ;
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';

function Business (){
    return (
        <Card style={{ width: '19rem' }} className='business'>
            <Card.Img  
            className='business-pic'
            src = {business.src}
            alt = {business.alt}
            />
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title className='business-name'>{business.name.toUpperCase()}</Card.Title>
                <Container fluid className='business-details'>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={8}  md={8} lg={8} xl={8} xxl={8}><Card.Text className='business-address'>{business.address}</Card.Text></Col>
                    <Col xs={4} md={4} lg={4} xl={4} xxl={4}><Card.Text className='business-category'>{business.category.toUpperCase()}</Card.Text></Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={8}  md={8} lg={8} xl={8} xxl={8}><Card.Text className='business-city'>{business.city}</Card.Text></Col>
                    <Col xs={4} md={4} lg={4} xl={4} xxl={4}><Card.Text className='business-rating'>{business.rating} stars</Card.Text></Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={8}  md={8} lg={8} xl={8} xxl={8} className='business-state-zip'><Card.Text className='business-state'>{business.state} </Card.Text><Card.Text className='business-zipcode'>{business.zipCode}</Card.Text></Col>
                    <Col xs={4} md={4} lg={4} xl={4} xxl={4}><Card.Text className='business-review'>{business.reviewCount} reviews</Card.Text></Col>
                </Row>
                </Container>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    );

}

export default Business;
```

BusinessList.js

```
import React from "react";
import Business from './Business'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container/';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row/';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col/';
import _ from 'lodash';
import './BusinessList.css';

function BusinessList (){

    //Creating Items 
    const items = []
    for (let index = 0; index < 12; index++) {
         items.push('Business')
    }
    //Mapping all items as Columns
    const listItems = items.map( item =>  {
        return ( <Col className={'business-items'}><Business/></Col>)
    });

    //Splitting Columns into a grid
    const gridItems = _.chunk(listItems,Math.floor((listItems.length)/3));

    const gridComponent = gridItems.map( items => {
        return (<Row>{items}</Row>);
    })



    return (
    <Container fluid={'lg'}>{gridComponent}
    </Container>
    )

}

export default BusinessList;
```

**CURRENT RESULT:**
[image]

**EXPECTED RESULT:**
[image]

Note, the Filter tabs currently do nothing except open a alert window when selected. They don't reload the page.